# Where are my add-ons for Garry's Mod?

Tags: garrys-mod

I have a windows 8.1 computer and I just got Garry's Mod yesterday so I decide to add the add-ons to make it more fun. When I downloaded a ragdoll add-on I go to Garry's mod, wait for to finish downloading, then when it's done, I have no ragdolls at all. So I search up "ragdolls" in the search box, nothing happens. Can someone please tell me if I missed something or if I did something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: check if the mod appears in the "Addons" section in the main menu.

1. If it appears, the addon may be broken or does only work for a certain game mode or map. (Which may be very weird for a ragdoll addon)
2. If it does not appear: the Steam Workshop stores all addon for the game as a `.gma` file in the following folder:
   `c:\Program files\Steam\steamapps\common\GarrysMod\garrysmod/garrysmod/addons`
   If the addon does not appears in this folder Steam didn't downloaded it. In this case try to un-subscribe and re-subscribe the mod.

Comment: Point 2. Not for everyone. Only the steam application is for `C:\>`, the steam games are not and you don't need them there.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you did not actually restart the game after the download finished. Restart your game fully, and try again.
Hold your SpawnMenu and find in the GAMES section the addon. It will contain a list of all the models and ragdolls that addon spawns, and you should be able to spawn them easily. If all else fails go to `YourSteamFolder/steamapps/common/GarrysMod/garrysmod/addons` and delete the .gma file relating to the addon (it should have the name of the addon in the name)

The steam folder defaults in `C:/Program Files/Steam` or on a 64bit system `C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam`